# angularjs ng-option obj confusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my markup

```
<select ng-model='selectedPerson' ng-options='obj.name for obj in people'></select>
```

and this is my js:

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope){
    $scope.selectedPerson = 0;
    $scope.selectedGenre = null;
    $scope.people = [
        {
            id: 0,
            name: 'Leon',
            music: [
                'Rock',
                'Metal',
                'Dubstep',
                'Electro'
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Chris',
            music: [
                'Indie',
                'Drumstep',
                'Dubstep',
                'Electro'
            ]
        }

    ];
});
```

why in the markup within the tag for ng-options, it uses obj.name for obj? but not people.name ? where does that obj came from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ng-options statement is essentially

```
foreach (var obj in people) 
{
    //do something with obj
}
```

You do not want to be acting on people but you do want to be acting on each element of people.

Answer (score 0):

`People` is the collection variable, `obj` is the variable for each element in the `People` collection.

Comment: I thought people.name to select people's name?